# In how many ways can you arrange the word "director" so that the vowels' orders stay the same?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> In how many ways can you arrange the word "director" so that the vowels' orders stay the same?

I found an answer where it said we find all possible permutations of this word and then divide it by the possible permutations of the vowels. The possible permutation of the vowels i, e, o are $3! = 6$.
The $6$ possible arrangements of the vowels are: ieo (the same as in the word), ioe, eio, oie, eoi, oei.
Now, we're supposed to keep the arrangements with the order ieo, then why do we have to divide with $6$ instead of $5$? What am I missing here?

Comment: All $6$ orders are equally likely, so one sixth of the (unrestricted) arrangements have the desired order.

Comment: I don't understand this. I'll come back after work.

Comment: Where did you get the divisor of $5$ from?

Comment: Out of the six words with the same order of consonants but different order of vowels, you need to keep exactly one of them. For example, out of the words director, dirocter, derictor, doricter, deroctir, and dorectir, you keep exactly one of them. That's "one" out of every "six" that you keep. Whatever the order of the consonants, you need to keep exactly "one" out of "six" possible permutations of the vowels. That's why you're "dividing by six". For the abstract details, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_division_(combinatorics)).

Comment: If your question is "what am I missing", then you're missing the principle behind division in this problem, in place of subtraction. See, if you have six objects and you want to count only one of them, you can remove (or *subtract*) $5$ and pick the remaining number of objects (which is $1$). On the other hand, if you have six objects and you want one of them, you *divide by* $6$ and pick those many (i.e. $1$) objects. That's the difference between subtraction and division, which you might need more examples and explanation to process.

Comment: I think that the question is not well defined. It is impossible to understand which arrangements are permissible and which are not. Do you mean that vowels must always be at places 2, 4 and 7??

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Reasonable response.  I speculate that the OP (i.e. original poster) intends to enumerate the subset of the $(8!)$ possible permutations where "i" comes before "e" and "o" comes after "e".  Based on this interpretation of the posting, I agree with the comment by lulu, immediately following the posting.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I find it really beautiful how you explained it.
I haven't been able to read the responses because I got fever, and haven't been able to do Math. Hope to come back and study all of it. Thank you for the responses.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer That was nice how you understood I didn't know the difference between division and subtraction :) I hope to learn as much Math one day, so I'll understand subtle things like this from people's questions :)

Comment: @alu Oh hey, thanks. Good to have been of help, even if it was in the comments. By the way, you *do* know the difference between subtraction and division (I'm very sure about this!) but this problem demanded that you know the difference between them in a combinatorial sense : which is something that everybody struggles with, because you need to count from first principles and solve examples to familiarize yourself with that. Don't worry, be patient, ask good questions here like this one when you can, and you will prosper. My guarantee.

Comment: I hope you recover from your fever as well. Professionalism demands that I work even when I'm not very well, but as a student one can afford to rest and come back better.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer My fever is gone now. I'm sorry you can't rest due to work, hope you somehow manage time to keep healthy. Thank you for your kind and thoughtful comments :)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Hello, I visited your website, you said I could ping you here. I want you write you an email if that's okay, I'm looking for friendship. Thank you.

Comment: @alu Oh yeah, sure. I'm not sure I can correspond very frequently and I'm barely active on MSE nowadays save for responses (that's because I'm applying for jobs, it's a busy period!), but feel free to pop me a mail particularly if you have some very directed queries. For what it's worth, I hold interests in advanced methods in combinatorics (not research-level though), so I would be able to help address questions like the one above.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I was thinking more of an emotional connection, I will talk about my struggles, I just don't know if you're comfortable with that, and comfortable with uncertainty and if you find talking about emotions valid, and if you like to be vulnerable. If you're busy then maybe not right now. I do have a combinatorics question, I'll email you.

Comment: @alu I can listen to you and provide advice but the basic problem is that I'm probably the busiest I've ever been in my life, which means I can't invest much time in replying to you. Having said that, I will try to give my best if and when you do write a mail, because that's the courtesy I owe you. I do not have a problem with your vulnerability, because stress whether at the student or researcher level is now prevalent everywhere and having companionship is really key, so I appreciate your need to be vulnerable. You can freely send me stuff to look at and I'll try and help you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First imagine listing off *all* arrangements of "director".  Write each down on a piece of paper. Now, on the back of each piece of paper, replace each vowel with an 'x'. eg, director -> dxrxctxr, etc.  Now put all the pieces of paper into folders, with each word going into a folder labeled by the "x-ed" version of that word.

### dxrxtxr

`director dirocter derictor deroctir dorectir doricter`

### drxxtxr

`driector driocter dreictor dreoctir droectir droicter`

etc.

You'll find that in each folder, there are exactly 6 words, exactly one of which has the vowels in the order `ieo`, so you'll get one word matching your condition for each folder. So, the answer is given by taking the total number of arrangements and dividing by 6. Now, you just need to count the total number of arrangements of `director`. (Careful - remember there are two `r`s!)

Answer (score 2):

DIRECTOR has vowels $IEO$. There are $6$ possible orders of vowels. The question to ask is this - will one of the orders of vowels have more number of words than others (for the given letters)? If you are still not convinced, take a simpler example -

$AIDE$

Total number of permutations of letters is $4! = 24$

But with the order of vowels fixed, there are $4$ possible words as $D$ can be in $4$ places -

$ \uparrow A \uparrow I \uparrow E \uparrow$

For every possible order of vowels, there are $4$ possible words. That leads to total number of words as,

$3! \cdot 4 = 4! = 24$

There is an alternate solution -

Place $IEO$ first in that order. Now place two $R's$ for which you can choose two places out of four or you can choose one of the four places. That is $10$ ways in total. Now you have $5$ letters and that gives choice of six places for the next letter, similarly seven for the next and eight for the last.

That is $10 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 = 3360$

Comment: I think you get too many! It is like saying that for each vowel arrangement you get 560 arrangements, which I find too large a number!

Comment: No, for every vowel arrangement you get $3360$x, a lot more than what you feel is already a large number :) In total you have $8! /2! = 20160$ arrangements of the letters in the word  $DIRECTOR$.

Comment: I don't understand how in the second solution, I can choose two places out of four or I can choose one of the four places.

Then how having 5 letters would give me 6 places for the next letter, 7 for the next, and 8 places for the last.

Comment: Once you write $_I_E_O_$, there are four spaces between them including left and right. Now if we take two $R$'s, they can either be in two of these four places or they can be together in one of the four places. Now we have for example, $_R_R_I_E_O_$. Do you see six choices for the next letter?

Comment: @MathLover Thank you for this beautiful solution. I tried to do the problem in this way at first but kept getting lost and confused with so many options. This way of seeing the problem's solution is helpful for me.

Comment: @MathLover whats up my old friend.. after you read my comment, i will delete it. I wonder why you do not answer questions anymore. I follow your profile regularly but do not see any new answers. Are you okey ?  I missed your clever answers. (Note: My nick name was Bulbasaur but i changed it ).

Answer (score 1):

Assume first that we distinguish all the letters, particularly both 'R's (like one is red and one is blue).

Imagine somebody made $8!$ arrangements. You found that in many cases vowels are in wrong order. You made corrections and realised that each arrangement is present six times in your list of obtained arrangements. Therefore you have to divide by six.

You can solve the task in other way. First, you choose the three places for vowels, that is $\binom 83$. These places define precise position of the vowels. Now you can arrange 5 consonants in $5!$ ways. Therefore the number of arrangements is $\binom 83\cdot 5!=8!/3!$, which matches the previous result.

Now we can deal with two Rs just like with vowels. Since interchanging their position doesn't change the arrangement, we have to divide the number of arrangements by two.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 3 vowels, then there are 3! (or 6) possible ways to permute them. Therefore, 1/6 of the arrangements have the vowel arrangement, “ieo,” for any word including these vowels.

You would divide the permutation of letters in “director” by 6 (or multiply the permutation by 1/6) to get rid of the cases where the vowels are not arranged as “ieo.” After that, deal with the two Rs by dividing by 2! (or 2).

If you were to divide by 5 instead, that would suggest that 1/5 of the permutations have the favorable vowel arrangement, “ieo,” which is false. Dividing by the number of unfavorable permutations for the three vowels would not give the right answer, as you would need to divide by every permutation of the vowels to get the permutations of “director” that follow that one specific vowel arrangement.

Therefore, the answer should be 8!/12.

Comment: You overlooked the fact that the word DIRECTOR contains two Rs.

Comment: Fixed it, my bad.